# angular route is working on dev but not in prod

Tags: javascript, angular

I am running Angular 2 project,

while I am on dev mode in localhost, everything works fine, but once I build a version of my application using (`npm run build: prod`) and my hit the route on the server,I get a 404 error and that the routing doesn't exist.

anyone got an idea about what this problem may be?
I just checked my configuration files and everything seems to be good so far because everything else works perfectly even other routes.

Comment: @Teebo the problem isn't in the routing config because its working perfectly on dev

Comment: change your base tag in your index.html

Answer (score 1):

Angular router, you must configure the server to return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file that it does not have.

Angular documation is very good you can take reference: 
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples

Apache: add a rewrite rule to the .htaccess

RewriteEngine On

## If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html

RewriteRule ^ /index.html